# Using multiple angular guards crashing page

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angularjs, typescript

I am trying to use seperate guards for seperate pages. I'm basically checking a bool parameter to understand if there's an user logged or not.

these are my two guard.ts codes

```
export class IsAuthenticatedGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(
      tap(isLoggedIn => {
        if(!isLoggedIn){
          //redirect
          this.router.navigate(['login']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

```
export class LoginPageGuard implements CanActivate {
  constructor(private authService: AuthService, private router: Router){}

  canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(
      tap(isLoggedIn => {
        if(isLoggedIn){
          //redirect
          this.router.navigate(['overview-page']);
        }
      })
    );
  }
}
```

and this is the code where I use guards (app.module.ts) I deleted pages between overview-page and login since they're not related.

```
  HttpClientModule,
    RouterModule.forRoot([
      //{path: '', component: UserTargetsComponent },
      //{path: '', component: NavbarComponent },
      {path: '', component: OverviewPageComponent, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedGuard]},
      {path: 'overview-page', component: OverviewPageComponent, canActivate:[IsAuthenticatedGuard]},
      {path: 'login', component: LoginComponent, canActivate: [LoginPageGuard]},
      {path: '**', component: NotFoundComponent, canActivate: [IsAuthenticatedGuard]}
    ])
```

For a brief time, it worked as I expected. If user is logged in it doesn't allow to go to login page, directs you to overview page and if user is not logged in, vice versa.

Now it just doesn't respond. just goes to main page (localhost:xxx/) when I go to login page by typing on browser bar. Same on overview-page. After few tries, pages usually crashes so I restart the angular app.

If I stop using canActivate on login page, everything works fine. when I put it back breaks again. I guess that's somehow causing this problem but how?

Any ideas? Probably I'm missing something small.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thats probably because your `LoginPageGuard` returns false if user is not logged in. So then it prevents the 'Login' route from being loaded, so where are they supposed to go? `LoginPageGuard` should return true if they are unauthenticated and false if they are with the re-route

```
canActivate(
    route: ActivatedRouteSnapshot,
    state: RouterStateSnapshot): Observable<boolean | UrlTree> | Promise<boolean | UrlTree> | boolean | UrlTree {
    return this.authService.isLoggedIn$.pipe(
      map(isLoggedIn => {
        if(isLoggedIn){
          //redirect
          this.router.navigate(['overview-page']);
          // if they are authenticated do not allow them to load login
          return false;
        }
       // if they are NOT authenticated, allow them to load this route
       return true;
      })
    );
```

Comment: Yes! thanks a lot. And why did you used map instead of tap? Is there a spesific reason? I'm pretty beginner in Angular

Comment: You shouldn't navigate in a guard. Just return the route you want.

Comment: `map` mutates the final value by wrapping it in an observable. `tap` does nothing to the stream value, just allows you to take some action and have access to the value. `map` will take the value you return from the stream wrap it in an observable, so the final result of the observable stream is whatever you return from `map`

Comment: So, shouldn't I do as O.MeeKoh suggested on his/her answer? If you say yes, can you add another answer for giving an example? Thanks! @MatthieuRiegler

Comment: @O.MeeKoh, believe me, you don't want 2 guards firing a navigation. Let the framework handle the navigation by returning the wanted route instead of false.

Comment: @MatthieuRiegler And how can I handle navigation afterwards instead of here? Can explain more detailed? Thanks!

Comment: @emreertunc return the urlTree you want in your `if`